# How to refresh observable while adding object in the observableArray?

Tags: knockout.js

I am new in knockout.js, I have tried to add and remove observable to an observableArray. I just take the first observable from the array and assign it to an input element to track the changes from the array. i.e.) When I add some observable to the observableArray it needs to be reflect in the input element.

Please refer my code below

**HTML:**

```
B[0] Value: <input data-bind="value: b"/>
<br/><br/>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th><th>B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: result">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: a()"/></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: b()"/></td>        
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
<button data-bind="click: remove">Remove</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function generate(data) {
    self = this;
    self.a = ko.observable(data.a);
    self.b = ko.observable(data.b); 
}
var arr = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:3}, {a:3, b:4}]
var obsarr = $.map(arr, function(data){ return new generate(data); });
var obsArray = {
    result : ko.observableArray(obsarr),
    b: ko.observable(obsarr[0].b)(),
    add: function(){
        var obj = new generate({a:4, b:4});
        obsArray.result.splice(0, 0, obj);
    },    
    remove: function(){
        obsArray.result.splice(0, 1);
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(obsArray);
```

But when I adding the observable it doesn't reflect to the input and when I change the input value after adding observable, it reflect to the second position (B[1](http://jsfiddle.net/p25w2h7f/1/)) of the array.

Is there anything I missed or I have implement anything wrong?

Please refer the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p25w2h7f/1/) for the above.

Thanks in advance :-)

**Updated:**

Two directional changes: [Two-Directional ObservableArray](http://jsfiddle.net/p25w2h7f/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed to return the *up to date* first item's `b` value. Don't forget to account for the case when there's no items!

```
obsArray.b = ko.computed(function () {
    var firstItem = obsArray.result()[0];
    if (firstItem) {
        return firstItem.b();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p25w2h7f/4/)

Also, if you want your input bindings to be *two-directional* don't unwrap the observable when declaring the binding. Note the lack of `()`.

```
<input data-bind="value: b"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p25w2h7f/2/).

In a couple of words:

You need not use brackets if you want to update values:

```
<td><input data-bind="value: a"/></td>
<td><input data-bind="value: b"/></td>
```

You need a computed to retreive the first element of the observable array:

```
var obsarr = ko.observableArray($.map(arr, function(data){ return new generate(data); }));
var obsArray = {
    result : obsarr,
    b: ko.computed(function() {
        return obsarr()[0].b();
    }),
    ......
```